# Insert json values in to dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 var g_Year = [
         { Year: "2011" },
         { Year: "2011" },
         { Year: "2010" },
         { Year: "2012" },
         { Year: "2011" },
         { Year: "2012" }
];
fxnDrop = function () {
        $.each(g_Year , function (index, Ele) {
            var iYear = g_Year [index].Year,
                sHtmlYear = '<option value="' + iYear + '">' + iYear + '</option>';
            $("#DropDown_Year").each(function (index, Ele) {
                $("#DropDown_Year").append(sHtmlYear);
                if (Ele.value != iYear) {
                    $("#DropDown_Year").remove(sHtmlYear);
                }
            });
        });
}
```

Here Im having multiple years, My goal is to display particular year only one time in the dropdown box.For Eg:2011 has to display only one time in the dropdown box. Can any one help me to do this. Im getting multiple 2011 values in dropbox.

Comment: Why isn't that just a flat array?

Comment: I don't think this line is right, `$("#DropDown_Year").each(...)` . You don't to loop an `id` which is going to be a one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
var fxnDrop = function() {
    var yearsArray = [];
    $.each(g_Year, function(index) { 
        if($.inArray(+g_Year[index].Year , yearsArray) == -1){
            yearsArray.push(+g_Year[index].Year);
        }
    });
    yearsArray.sort();
    var sHtmlYear = '';
    $.each(yearsArray , function(i){
        sHtmlYear += '<option value="'+ yearsArray[i] +'">' 
                         + yearsArray[i]  + '</option>'; 
    });
     $("#DropDown_Year").append(sHtmlYear);
};

fxnDrop(); ​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/JWsZh/)**

Comment: @sushanth:- Just show them the right way ...Do not write the code on behalf of people ..:):)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`Jquery.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function : for exe:-

```
  var categories=[];
         if ($.inArray(value.category, categories)==-1){
        categories.push(value.category);
        }
```

`categories` will hold the unique categories you need
**Updated**
[**[SEE LIVE DEMO][2]**](http://jsfiddle.net/3wHfB/34/)

Comment: It is only for creating an array and pushing values in to array. my problem is that checking the json values and putting it in to dropbox

Answer (score 0):

try this.. used Jquery.inArray()  as mentioned by @pranav

```
var yeararray= [];

fxnDrop = function () {
    $.each(g_Year , function (index, Ele) {
       if ($.inArray(Ele.Year, yeararray)==-1) {
        var iYear = g_Year [index].Year,
        sHtmlYear = '<option value="' + iYear + '">' + iYear + '</option>';
        $("#DropDown_Year").each(function (index, Ele) {
            $("#DropDown_Year").append(sHtmlYear);
            if (Ele.value != iYear) {
                $("#DropDown_Year").remove(sHtmlYear);
            }
        });
          yeararray.push(Ele.Year);
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var g_Year = [
         { Year: "2011" },
         { Year: "2011" },
         { Year: "2010" },
         { Year: "2012" },
         { Year: "2011" },
         { Year: "2012" }
];
g_Year.sort(function(o1, o2){return o1.Year > o2.Year} );

// use reduce function
var uniqueG_Year = g_Year.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
  if(previousValue.length == 0 || previousValue[previousValue.length-1].Year != currentValue.Year)
    previousValue.push(currentValue);
  return previousValue;
}, []);

// or simply use filter
var uniqueG_YearFiltered = g_Year.filter(function(element, index, array){
  return (index == 0 || array[index-1].Year != element.Year)
});
```